# how to make the same design work on all screens?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I made a draggable FAB. Can only be dragged horizontally. But it's not working correctly on other screens. Let me show with SS.

İt's from emulator:

[image]

İt's from real device:

[image]

And there is my FAB Controller class

```
class FabController extends GetxController {
  double width = 0.0;
  double height = 0.0;
  var offset = FABButonDefaultKonum.obs;



  moveFab(Offset newOffset) {
    offset.value = newOffset;

    update();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

There is my constants class:

```
double newHeight = Get.size.height - padding.top - padding.bottom;
double newWidth = Get.size.width - padding.right - padding.left;
Offset FABButonDefaultKonum = Offset(newWidth * 0.8, newHeight * 0.85);
```

And last one is Fab button:

```
Obx(
                    () {
                    
                      return Positioned(
                        left: fabController.offset.value.dx,
                        top: fabController.offset.value.dy ,
                        child: Draggable(
                          axis: Axis.horizontal,
                          feedback: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                              color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                            ),
                            child: FloatingActionButton(
                                key: fabKey,
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                                child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  print(fabController.offset);
                                }),
                          ),
                          child: Obx(
                            () {
                             
                              return Badge();
                            },
                          ),
                          childWhenDragging: Container(),
                          onDragEnd: (details) {
                            Offset newOffset = details.offset;

                            if (details.offset.dx <= newWidth / 2) {
                              newOffset =
                                  Offset(newWidth * 0.05, newHeight * 0.90);
                            } else {
                              newOffset =
                                  Offset(newWidth * 0.8, newHeight * 0.90);
                            }

                            if (!_isLeave) fabController.moveFab(newOffset);

                            print(fabController.offset.value.toString() +
                                " ***");
                          },
                          onDragStarted: () {
                            _isLeave = false;
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Please help me. How can I make a responsive design?

I tried `Get.height` and `Get.width`. But didn't work.

Comment: If you have set the bottom navigation bar height to some concrete values then you can add the value of the height in the FAB button, that way your button will be placed always above your navigation bar